# Click html elements below a swf file - is it possible?

Tags: html, flash

You would think that this is the easiest think to find an answer for.

I cannot find an answer anywhere that says a simple yes or no.

I have an swf overlay, please see here... http://goo.gl/mPylnG

All I want to do is to be able to click html elements below. Simple you think.

This is my code below in my body...

```
<div id="eCard">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="images/suzuki-xmas-ecard-web.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
</div>
<div id="snowContent"></div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var flashvars = {};
var params = {
    wmode: "transparent"
};
var attributes = {};
attributes.id = "snow";
swfobject.embedSWF("images/snow-storm.swf", "snowContent", "100%", "100%", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
```

If anyone has a link to the answer please share cause I cannot find one.

Thanks
Josh

Comment: surely if you have put the swf on top of the elements then there will be no way to click the elements underneath it.  If you are just wanting an overlay snow effect, why not use a [javascript plugin](http://www.jqueryrain.com/2012/04/top-jquery-snow-falling-effect-plugin-tutorial-with-example/) instead of flash

Comment: The snow is not quite as stylish. Though css pointer-events:none does a similar thing but don't work in IE. So your saying 'No' it's not possible?

Comment: Another solution could be to write a plugin that will cycle through all your objects underneath the swf and any clickable elements it can create an empty absolutely positioned element (matching the offsets of the original element) that you can click on top of your swf, seems a lot of work though - unless there's already an existing plugin

Comment: Thats a very clever idea. But I don't have the skills.

Comment: How's this: http://jsfiddle.net/Wz7vU/1/, you can see that links aren't clickable without the js

Comment: Dude that is genius thank you! Though will it mess with Analytics? You need to give this answer I think

Comment: Answer added - please note I have changed the code from the above fiddle as that link across a couple of lines wasn't working properly

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply make the swf canvas navigate to the Suzuki web site www.suzuki-gb.co.uk?
Just create an invisible button that is the entire size of the canvas.

...Once they arrive at the site, then they can follow the social networks from there.
What other links are there?

Try this maybe? 
http://seb.ly/demos/JSSnowNew/snow3d.html

I'm not sure this can be done with a flash document as it sits within a plugin that occupies that space. Even with the swf set as transparent the flash file takes control of the mouse within that `object` or `embed` region (try to right click... you see?)

Comment: That would work for my example, but I've been asked to apply this to a website and I'm struggling :/

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery to [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the links in your document and put them onto a masque layer above the flash.  The following jQuery should clone your links with all events attached so any analytic events attached to the click should also be copied

```
var linklayer = $('<div id="links"></div>');
$('body').append(linklayer);

//change the selector to include anything that is clickable
$('a').each(function() { 
    var link = $(this),
        clone = link.clone(true, true),
        cloneWrap = $('<span class="link-wrap"></span>');
        link.addClass('hide');

    cloneWrap.css({ 'top': link.offset().top, 'left': link.offset().left }).append(clone);

    var margin = link[0].offsetLeft - link.offset().left;
    if (margin > 0) {
        clone.css('margin-left', margin); //this bit makes the link go over two lines
    }
    linklayer.append(cloneWrap);
});
```

**Css**

```
#links {position:absolute; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0; z-index:100;} /*z-index needs to be higher than the swf z-index*/
#links > .link-wrap {display:inline-block; position:absolute;} /*link wrap needed for links over two lines*/

.hide {visibility:hidden;}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/qU4UE/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<div id="eCard">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://mailers.suzukibulletin.co.uk/2013/xmas/e-card/images/suzuki-xmas-ecard-web.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
</div>
<div id="snowContent"></div>
<div id="ecard-proxy"></div>
```

CSS:

```
object {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
#ecard-proxy{
   left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    display:block;
    z-index:1000;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#eCard{
    width:auto;
    height:377px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var flashvars = {};
var params = {
    wmode: "transparent"
};
var attributes = {};
attributes.id = "snow";
swfobject.embedSWF("http://mailers.suzukibulletin.co.uk/2013/xmas/e-card/images/snow-storm.swf", "snowContent", "100%", "100%", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);

    $("#ecard-proxy").click(function(){
        // 
        $("#eCard").trigger("click");
    });
     $("#eCard").click(function(){
         alert("card cicked");
     });

});
```

Check [Fuddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sesubash/64fmf/)